# Make marker animate to double in size on click

Tags: jquery, css, leaflet, marker

I am trying to make a lealet divIcon change size when it is clicked on. I have tried adding CSS but it does not work.

I have a basic fiddle made to show the custom divIcon but no sure whether to add a onclick event to the marker or add a button somewhere else to trigger the click. I would like to animate it to double the size but keep it in the correct location. Any suggestions where yo start or if I am attempting the wrong method would be great, thanks

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0es3wuhm/)

The HTML is :

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

The CSS is :

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
#map {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

/* Counter-productive?
.location-pin {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}*/

.location-pin img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: -26px 0 0 -13px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #32383e;
}

.pin {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #32383e;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -43px 0 0 -30px;
}

.pin:after {
  content: '';
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pulse {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}

.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -16px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 2.5s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(94, 190, 255, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #2d99d3;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
```

The JS is :

```
var zoom = 10;
var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
  attribution: osmAttrib,
  detectRetina: true
});

window.map = new L.Map('map', {
  layers: [osm],
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 18,
  center: [51.505, -0.09],
  zoom: 10,
  zoomControl: false

});

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
  className: 'location-pin',
  html: '<img src="https://www.faces2places.co.uk/img/jules.jpg"><div class="pin"></div><div class="pulse"></div>',
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  //iconAnchor: [18, 30]
  iconAnchor: [10, 33]
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {
  icon: myIcon
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to listen to the click rather be it on icon itself or some other button, once clicked you could add a new class to the icon, that scales it 2x and for animation you can transition that scale.

a new class that contains: `transform: scale(2);`  this class is added on click.
and in the old class (`.location-pin`) you could add `transition: transform 0.3s ease;` 

but this could mess with the position of the pin on the map.

Comment: I have tried that but no good and ideally I would like to change the size from an external button, I think I cannot change it due to not having a Div ID?

Comment: I've quickly fiddled this up: https://jsfiddle.net/n62qa8pz/
*note*: i've fixed the pin as well as the button for the demonstration purpose.
it seemed like pin already had some transition applied, which rendered our transition useless, so instead i went for the animation property to achieve the same result.

Comment: Yes it works good on the sample as only one marker but I have 2 and it makes them both go to the top left corner, but I should be able to work with it, thanks